# Past Continuous + Past Simple

Tags: past-simple, past-continuous

If two actions were happening at the same time, we can use both **Past Simple** + **Past Simple** and **Past Simple** + **Past Continuous** or conversely

*While **he was having** his breakfast, **I was reading** the newspaper*

*While **he had** his breakfast, **I read** the newspaper*

The quetion is can I combine **Past Continuous** with **Past Simple**?

*While **you were walking**, **I broke** the window*

I want the **"walk"** action be like a process while the **"break"** action - like a fact. If I say

*While **you were walking**, **I was breaking** the window*

then both actions would be a process. The same with

*While **you walked**, **I broke** the window*

both actions are facts.

Comment: Yes, you can. _While you were walking_ indicates the period of time during which the breakage happened.

Comment: isn't "While you walked, I broke" equal to "While you were walking, I broke", though?
From my understanding, "While" already conveys the idea of a continuous tense, making the continuous tense optional here. Same with "While you worked, I had a smoke" and "While you were working, I had a smoke".